# How to resolve circular dependency with friend declarations in C++?

Tags: c++, friend, circular-dependency

Why doesn't the following code compile and how can I fix it? The error I get is:

> Use of undeclared identifier 'Foo'

although `Foo` is clearly declared and defined at the point where the error occurs (at the `friend` declaration in `Bar`).

**foo.h**:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include "bar.h" // needed for friend declaration in FooChild

class Foo {
public:
  void Func(const Bar&) const;
};

class FooChild : public Foo {
  friend void Bar::Func(FooChild*);
};

#endif
```

**foo.cpp**:

```
#include "foo.h"

void Foo::Func(const Bar& B) const {
  // do stuff with B.X
}
```

**bar.h**:

```
#ifndef BAR_H
#define BAR_H

#include "foo.h"

class Bar {
public:
  void Func(FooChild*) {}
private:
  int X;
  friend void Foo::Func(const Bar&) const; // "use of undeclared identifier 'Foo'"
};

#endif
```

[Here](http://goo.gl/GUu8cf)'s a compilable online version of the above code.

Comment: This would be a lot less messy if you didn't need to `friend` things like that. Keep your `private`s private.

Comment: @tadman The reason I used `friend` instead of making a getter for `X` is that way only the code that needs `X` has access to it, instead of giving all code that has access to a `Bar` the access to `X` as well.

Comment: Seeing things like this is usually a sign of a broken object-oriented design. If one thing *needs* access to `X`, make an accessor. Locking things down with `private` and `friend` is usually overkill when being disciplined about not calling the accessor in the first place is often good enough. Hopefully you trust yourself enough.

Comment: @tadman My main intention was to make the _interface_ of my classes simpler for others who use them ("What's this `GetX()` even though we aren't supposed to use it?" etc.).

Comment: Having another class monkey around with your internals is always suspicious from a design perspective, so either way you've got problems. In one sense, if you can't explain why you're not supposed to use it in the name or associated documentation, maybe you don't have a very good reason not to.

Answer (score 3):

Put `FooChild` in a header file of its own.

foo.h:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

class Bar;

class Foo {
public:
  void Func(const Bar&) const;
};

#endif
```

foochild.h:

```
#ifndef FOOCHILD_H
#define FOOCHILD_H

#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

class FooChild : public Foo {
  friend void Bar::Func(FooChild*);
};

#endif
```

Comment: I remember it was behaving as mentioned in my (now deleted) answer, that it wasn't allowed to declare specific class member functions as `friend`, but only the whole class, or using a free standing function. Has this been fixed with the current standard (c++-11)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, it's possible to declare member functions as friends in C++11, although I don't know whether or not it was possible in earlier standards.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Section 11.3/5 gives examples of member functions being declared as friends.