# Bilateral friend functions in C++: how to make it compile?

Tags: c++, friend-function

I have the following C++ files:

A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "B.h"

class A
{
    private:
        int m_a;
    public:
        A();

        void a(const B &b);

    friend void B::b(const A &a);
};

#endif // A_H
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
#include 

A::A()
{
    m_a = 100;
}

void A::a(const B &b)
{
    std::cout << b.m_b << ".\n";
}
```

B.h

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

class A;

class B
{
    private:
        int m_b;
    public:
        B();
        void b(const A &a);

    friend void A::a(const B &b); // error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class A'
};

#endif // B_H
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"
#include 
#include "A.h"

B::B()
{
    this->m_b = 101;
}

void B::b(const A &a)
{
    std::cout << a.m_a << ".\n";
}
```

When I try to compile this, it gives me:

> error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class A'.

How should I fix this?

Comment: Which line is the error line?

Comment: I think that the class definition of B needs to go before a, and the functions of the class a need to go after a is defined as well. You might have to add: class A; class B; at the top of the header "a", as well as move "a"'s functions below A.

Comment: Maybe it is duplicate and not solved yet, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535434/how-to-resolve-circular-dependency-with-friend-declarations-in-c

Comment: Do you really need friend functions? Couldn't you just have accessor functions in both classes?

Comment: @NutCracker see my edit please.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I try to learn C++. I know friend functions shouldn't be used. Let's say it is a pedagocial scenario.

Comment: Try to put `#include "A.h"` in _B.h_ because class B needs to know whole declaration of class A.

Comment: @NutCracker This doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: First, you don't need `#include "B.h"` in _A.cpp_ file. Remove `class A;` statement from the _B.h_ file and then `#include "A.h"` in _B.h_

Comment: @NutCracker this will move the error in A.h header. But you do need B.h in A.cpp. You access private fields from B in A.cpp.

Comment: You can't accomplish this in C++.

Comment: Can you try to put `class A; #include "A.h"` (one below another) in your _B.h_?

Comment: @molbdnilo Hmmm... are you sure? It seems to me so, but I would need some proof if possible :). Like documentation... Althoug logically makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to have a member functiion of B a friend of A and a member function of A a friend of B.

There are several ways to overcome this.

1. Write one or both functions as non-members. Make them friends of both classes if neseccary.
2. Make the entire class a friend of the other class. If that's too broad a permission, extract a smaller class to serve as a friend.
3. Turn both classes into class templates (the template parameter does not matter).

   ```
   enum unit {u};

   template <unit X> class A;

   template <unit X> class B
   {
       static void foo() {}
       static void bar() { A<X>::foo(); }
       friend void A<X>::bar();
   };

   template <unit X> class A
   {
       static void foo() {}
       static void bar() { B<X>::foo(); }
       friend void B<X>::bar();
   };

   using AX = A<u>;
   using BX = B<u>;
   ```

Comment: It seems most comprehensive answer which deserves to be accepted

Answer (score 3):

Actually in your case, your are creating a circular dependency.

It is generally avoided with forward declaration but as far as i know C++ doesn't let us to do forward declaration for member functions so it seems impossible now to me.

But it is possible to break circular dependency when you declare `class` as `friend`.

a.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "b.h"

class B;

class A
{
    private:
        int m_a;
    public:
        A();

        void a(const B &b);

    friend class B;
};

#endif // A_H
```

a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include <iostream>

A::A()
{
    m_a = 100;
}

void A::a(const B &b)
{
    std::cout << b.m_b << ".\n";
}
```

b.h

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

class A;

class B
{
    private:
        int m_b;
    public:
        B();
        void b(const A &a);

    friend class A;
};

#endif // B_H
```

b.cpp

```
#include "b.h"
#include "a.h"
#include <iostream>

B::B()
{
    this->m_b = 101;
}

void B::b(const A &a)
{
    std::cout << a.m_a << ".\n";
}
```

Comment: This is similar to @zmb's answear. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to setup a circular dependency. This is a terrible thing to handle and it is simply forbidden in plenty of use cases. In C++, the rule is that you can use any object as soon as it is *declared*, even if it is fully defined later. The problem is that members are only declared by the definition of a class. So if one class (say B) needs to use is its definition *members* of another class (say A), then A has to be defined before B. As you cannot have A defined before B and B defined before A at the same time, you will not be able to achieve what you want in C++.

If you find yourself trying to setup a member of A as friend in B and a member of B as friend in A, then you have a general design problem. If it makes sense (on a model point of view) it can be solved by making one full class as friend (this is @zmb's answer), or changing the member functions to non members. But I strongly advise you to go back one step and try to build a hierachical model instead of a circular one. Unfortunately, it becomes a design question and not a programming one, so I am afraid I shall not be able to help you more in SO...

Answer (score 1):

You are using an unknown type:

```
friend void A::a(const B &b);
```

The compiler only knows that the class A exists, but nothing else.
You can declare the entire class A as a friend instead:

```
friend class A;
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But let's say we don't want to expose class B to other functions which supposedly exist in A.